# Jquery dialog removes my original image

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui

So I'm trying to make my own jQuery plugin. Whenever I click on a picture a jQuery dialog opens and places another image inside of the dialog. If I click on that image then it will go back to the original image etc... The only problem is that when I click on the original image for the first time it opens the dialog. But when the dialog opens it removes the original image on my website. So I only have the dialog on my website. Here is my HTML code:

```
<body>
    <div class="imageHolder">
    <img src="http://www.c-and-a.com/iview/FRONT_ZOOM2X/148243_1.jpg"
         data-swap="http://www.c-and-a.com/iview/BACK_ZOOM2X/148243_1.jpg" id="images">
        </div>


<script>

    $(function() {

        $(document).ready( function() {
            $('img').jqueryPlugin();
        });

    });

</script>
</body>
```

And here's my javascript code:

```
(function($) {


    $.fn.jqueryPlugin = function() {


        $("img").click(function() {
            var _this = $(this);
            var current = _this.attr("src");
            var swap = _this.attr("data-swap");
            _this.attr('src', swap).attr("data-swap",current);

            $( "img" ).dialog({
                dialogClass: "no-close",
                width: 'auto',
                height: 'auto',
                resize: "auto"
            });
        });



    };






})(jQuery);
```

Comment: How bout creating a fiddle?

Answer (score 0):

seems like you've got two doc ready statements there....which should not be related to your issue.

Sounds like a problem I encountered too. Solved it by cloning the object instead of using it directly. See:
https://api.jquery.com/clone/

edit: haha, sorry about that. The above could be related...But your problem is more likely to be caused by your inprecise selector. Use ID's or classes...not 'img' as an selector.

Also, consider declaring your variables outside of your functions because now you're redeclaring them every time you're using the function. You could also try to move your data to an object.

Comment: I've changed them into ID's. It's still not working. 

$("#images").click(function() {
            var _this = $(this);
            var current = _this.attr("src");
            var swap = _this.attr("data-swap");
            _this.attr('src', swap).attr("data-swap",current);

            $("#images").dialog({
                dialogClass: "no-close",
                width: 'auto',
                height: 'auto',
                resize: "auto"
            });
        });